# Issue with console data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, web-services

I am developing registration form in my app,here total data is successfully inserted into the `database` i getting status also 200 response.but here i need to get the data from console,here i am developing below code.

```
  NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"customer_name=%@&customer_email=%@&customer_mobile=%@&customer_password=%@&customer_address=%@",name.text,email.text,mobile.text,password.text,add.text];
    NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://customer_registration.php"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
```

Here i get response

```
responseData: 
  [
      {
        "customer_id": "14",
        "success": "Successfully Registered"
      }
    ]
```

But i need `success` key then i will call

```
  if (success==Successfully Registered) {

    LoginViewController *tc=[LoginViewController new];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tc animated:YES];

}
```

i have tried so many ways but i confused when it will getting can you please suggest me ,thank you@

Comment: where is your NSJSONSerialization method

Comment: while I'm putting NSJSONSerialization also its not working @Karthik

Comment: show your code my friend

Comment: (
   {
      "customer_id": "33”,
      "success":"SuccessfullyRegistered”
    }
)

Comment: this is response i get the when I'm using NSJSONSerialization @karthik

Comment: good my friend, have u show ur full code , i add the NSJSONSerialization method

Comment: the above first code @karthik

Comment: your response is started with **[** -- NSArray **{** -- it contains NSMutableDictionary, remember that always start your NSJSONSerialization depend upon your response , have a nice day my friend, if my answer is hopeful, plz give the up vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *myRequestString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"customer_name=%@&customer_email=%@&customer_mobile=%@&customer_password=%@&customer_address=%@",name.text,email.text,mobile.text,password.text,add.text];
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ myRequestString UTF8String ] length: [ myRequestString length ] ];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ [ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] initWithURL: [ NSURL URLWithString:@"http://customer_registration.php"]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

NSError* error;
NSArray* result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:returnData
                                                   options:kNilOptions

                                     error:&error];
 NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

if ([[[result objectAtIndex:0] ObjectForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"Successfully Registered"]) 
{
 LoginViewController *Login=[LoginViewController new];

// In case of NavigatinController u added
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Login animated:YES];

//In case with out NavigatinController
[self presentViewController:Login animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```